# remove certain words from paragraphs using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a web page like this:

```
<p class="author">By ... on Jan 23, 2012</p>
<p class="content">(some content)</p>

<p class="author">By ... on Jan 23, 2012</p>
<p class="content">(some content)</p>

<p class="author">By ... on Jan 23, 2012</p>
<p class="content">(some content)</p>

...
```

I would like to use jquery to remove the words "By" and "on" from p.author, the result would be:

```
<p class="author">... Jan 23, 2012</p>
<p class="content">(some content)</p>
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about the context of this situation, but would it not be better to do this on the server by altering whatever code you use to pull this out of a database (or from another source)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".author").each( function(){
    var text = this.firstChild.nodeValue;
    this.firstChild.nodeValue = text.replace( /(^By|\bon\b)/g, "" );
});
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$('.author').each(function(){
$(this).text($(this).text().replace(/on|by/g,""))
});
```

Comment: Inside `each` loop `this` points to `DOM` element. So you need to first create a jQuery object before calling `text` method.

Comment: looking it up in the jquery documentation now.

Comment: yep you're right. It's strange tho, because when you make a jquery plugin, your function gets a jquery instance. My intuition would be that all other functions handling DOM elements would get one too.

Answer (score 2):

No need of additional `each`:

```
$("p.author").text(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(/(By|on)/g, '');
});
```

Comment: There is 2 implicit `eaches` in there without much savings in code

Comment: You are right, sure. But I prefer to use opportunities jQuery offers, and if we can use `function` as an argument to `text` - I find it really convinient.